# How to get video from camera Intent and save it to a directory?

Tags: android, video, filesystems, video-processing, android-camera-intent

Is it possible to have code similar to the following that does the same for video?

```
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
            // camera mode was canceled.
        } else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

            // Took a picture, use the downsized camera image provided by default
            Bitmap cameraPic = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            if (cameraPic != null) {
                try {
                    savePic(cameraPic);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e(DEBUG_TAG, "saveAvatar() with camera image failed.", e);
                }
            }
```

What I am trying to do is to be able to take a video using the Camera Intent and save that video or a copy of that video to my specific directory. This is the code i have to take the clip:

```
private void initTakeClip(){
    Button takeClipButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.takeClip);
    takeClipButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
            String strVideoPrompt = "Take your Video to add to your timeline!";
            Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(cameraIntent, strVideoPrompt), TAKE_CLIP_REQUEST);
            }
    });
}
```

I just don't know how to go about then getting that specific video that was just taken and then copying it into my sd/appname/project_name/ directory.

The same is the case for getting the name/file location when adding a clip already from memory to my directory:

```
 private void initAddClip(){
    Button addClipButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addClip);
    addClipButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
            String strAvatarPrompt = "Choose a picture to use as your avatar!";
            Intent pickVideo = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
            pickVideo.setType("video/*");
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(pickVideo, strAvatarPrompt), ADD_CLIP_REQUEST);

        }
    });
}
```

Any/All help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 8):

First what you need to do is get the URI from the onActivityResult like this:

```
private String videoPath = "";

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    Uri vid = data.getData();
    videoPath = getRealPathFromURI(vid);


}

public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentUri) {
    String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
    int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor.getString(column_index);
}
```

Then once you have the actual path stored as videoPath then you can store that using

```
try {

  FileInputStream fis = openFilePath(videoPath);

  //this is where you set whatever path you want to save it as:

  File tmpFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"VideoFile.3gp"); 

  //save the video to the File path
  FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(tmpFile);

  byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
  int len;
  while ((len = fis.read(buf)) > 0) {
    fos.write(buf, 0, len);
  }       
  fis.close();
  fos.close();
 } catch (IOException io_e) {
    // TODO: handle error
 }
```

Comment: FileInputStream fis = openFilePath(videoPath);    In this statement I confused , I can't read it......Can you help me?

Comment: Yes what is openFilePath.....new FileInputStream(realURIhere) ?